# How to view coinbase transaction activity

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

The node.js tests : https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node/tree/master/test & documentation :  https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node do not appear to describe tests or functionality that return all activity on account. 
I'm attempting to access all buys and sells of currencies for an account.
Is this functionality available ? Can view via an api call buys and sells for an account for each currency coinbase supports ?

Update : im attempting to access cummulative sum of all purchases for all currencies within coinbase portfolio. Is my method above the canocical way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [List transactions](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#list-transactions):

> Lists account’s transactions. See [transaction resource](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#the-transaction-resource) for more information.
>
> #### HTTP REQUEST
>
> ```
> GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/transactions
> ```
>
> #### SCOPES
>
> - `wallet:transactions:read`
>
> #### Example request
>
> ```
> var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
>
> var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY',
>                          'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'});
>
> client.getAccount('2bbf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659ede', function(err, account) {
>   account.getTransactions(function(err, txs) {
>     console.log(txs);
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: The "cumulative sum"?  So, basically, the current balance?

Comment: im attempting to access how much has been spent buying each crypto in the portfolio since account opening. In order to discover if account is in profit or loss at current prices. For example : user 'A' has spent 300 euros on Bitcoin and current balance is 320 euros.